# Deleting pods from Openshift with Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, openshift

before this question i used jenkins command line but it is not effective for me so i wanted to write something that automates the process but not from terminal. As i looked up i can create a pipeline or freestyle project, but i am new to this i could not understand the things that i see. Is there a way to automate this process?

This was my jenkins cli to delete the pods:
`kubectl delete pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded'`

Can i generate this code and turn this to that will be applied in all projects and delete pods from openshift ?
Thanks for the help

Comment: What pods are you talking about? Are they Jenkins Pods? Or other pods in Openshift?

Comment: pods at workloads